# « Wooden splint » en français

Tags: anglais, terminologie, science

Il y en a un outil de chimie dont je sais le nom en anglais mais pas en français.
C'est le "wooden splint" ou "glowing wooden splint".
J'ai essayé avec [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splint_(laboratory_equipment)), et malheureusement j'ai trouvé l'article en anglais seulement.
Google ne m'a pas aidé beaucoup.
Quel est le mot technique en français?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On l'appelle communément une *bûchette incandescente*.

Bûchette signifie petite bûche : *small log*, *stick*.